# Redis inverted replication

Tags: database, redis

I am trying to switch to Redis database and during the replication stage I got some issues.

The problem is that I want to have a single database (central) to which the other separate databases (different data in each one) automatically send the data to.

In the documentation I find that normal replication sends data from one central db (master) to the slaves not the opposite.

Comment: my question would be why do you have different databases producing content? is that something fixed in your design or could you have everything written to one instance?

Comment: Hi, It is because I dont want to load different request in one second in a single database, and i want to have a single data base in which all my data to its.

Comment: "because I dont want to load different request in one second in a single database" - yes I get this, but is this due to a proven performance bottleneck?

Comment: In MySql yes, i have one databases in which I have a performance problem because I send many request in the same time.